# Difference between %zu and %lu in C

Tags: c, printf, string-formatting, size-t

What is the difference between `%zu` and `%lu` in string formatting in C? `%lu` is used for `unsigned long` values and `%zu` is used for `size_t` values, but in practice, `size_t` is just an `unsigned long`. CppCheck complains about it, but both work for both types in my experience.

Is `%zu` just a standardized way of formatting `size_t` because `size_t` is commonly used, or is there more to it?

Comment: Except that `size_t` could be `unsigned long long` and then `%lu` would be wrong but `%zu` is still correct.

Comment: *"in practice, size_t is just an unsigned long"*. No, in 32-bit MS VC `size_t` is 32-bits, in 64-bit it is 64 bits. But `long` is 32 bits in both.

Comment: An `unsigned long` is at least 32-bit.  `size_t` is at least 16-bit.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> but in practice, `size_t` is just an `unsigned long`

Not necessarily.  There are systems with a 32 bit `long` and a 64 bit `size_t`.  MSVC is one of them.

Given the following:

```
printf("long: %zu\n", sizeof(long));
printf("long long: %zu\n", sizeof(long long));
printf("size_t: %zu\n", sizeof(size_t));
```

Compiling under MSVC 2015 in x86 mode outputs:

```
long: 4
long long: 8
size_t: 4
```

While compiling in x64 mode outputs:

```
long: 4
long long: 8
size_t: 8
```

Having a separate size modifier for `size_t` ensures you're using the correct size.

Comment: From what I understand, the size of size_t is implementation and machine dependent, and using %zu makes formatting easier and independent of anything. Am I correct?

Comment: @Brogolem35 Yes, the `z` modifier is specifically for `size_t`, so it will be correct for whatever the size of `size_t` happens to be.

Comment: In practice, `size_t` is usually the same size as a pointer (but there are likely to be some exceptions - EDIT e.g. AS/400 has 128-bit pointers and 32-bit `size_t`!).